# WPF Binding в значение - динамический биндинг

Tags: c#, wpf

вопросик есть, как можно передать команде сразу два параметра, при этом что один из параметров состояние текущего элемента.

Пример есть Checkbox. У него есть Tag и IsChecked. Так вот, мне надо передавать и Tag и IsChecked. 
Делаю примерно так:

```
checkBox.CommandParameter = new ValueTuple<XXX, object>((x) checkBox.Tag, checkBox.IsChecked);
```

Но проблема в том, что значение IsChecked всегда false. Чувствую что надо выюзать биндинг, но вопрос как тогда передавать?

Тема в том, что надо из определенного словаря составить набор контролов, хотелось бы сделать по типу MVVM и все дела.

Ну и понятно, что все надо сделать в codebehind'e.

Comment: Вам стоит обратить внимание на ``MultiBinding``: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350598/passing-two-command-parameters-using-a-wpf-binding

Comment: @alladuh,  мне нельзя юзать в принципе xaml, мне нужен вариант только на C#. Я уже передаю два параметра, но мне нужно отслеживать изменение в данном случае IsCheked самого элемента. В моем варианте он всегда false, потому как только инициализируется сам контрол ему и прописывается commanParameter, надо толи обновлять CommandParameter, толи придумать вариант Binding'a

Comment: `мне нельзя юзать в принципе xaml` - тогда лучше вообще не использовать WPF, ибо без XAML и без MVVM подхода он убог и тогда уж лучше использовать WinForms.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, в данном случае мне нельзя юзать xaml. Проект весь на WPF, тут надо просто из Legacy перевести на WPF полностью (кусочек небольшой остался), там динамические настройки. Их количество неопределенно, а писать через события мне противно. В логику мне лазать нельзя, я бы просто выпилил бы гребанный приватный сеттер на значение, и привязал бы биндинги напрямую, а по изменению обновлял в бдшке. Но нет - низя. Так что сейчас я регаю команду и определяю, что надо обновить значение. Там где-то в логике идет поиск конкретной настройки и обновляет ее.