# WPF Multibinding Checkbox Комманды как задать корректно конвертер значений (Codebehind)

Tags: c#, wpf

Дарова, этот вопрос исходит из этого поста: [WPF Binding в значение - динамический биндинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1016248/wpf-binding-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3?noredirect=1#comment1726356_1016248)

Пришел к выводу, что можно запилить мультибиндинг значений на изменение Checkbox'a, который должен вызвать команду и передать эти значения в команду, как только изменить свое состояние.

Кусочек кодяры:

```
 var mb = new MultiBinding();

 mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding() { Source = (XXX) checkBox.Tag, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
 mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(checkBox.IsChecked)), RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self});
 mb.Converter = new Converter1();

 checkBox.CommandParameter = mb;
 checkBox.Command = ((ViewModel1) DataContext).Command1;
```

Кусочек конвертера:

```
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new ValueTuple<XXX, object>((XXX) values[0], values[1]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new[] { null, value };
    }
```

Проблема, в том, что он пытается прокинуть в команду параметр именно мультибиндиг, а не значения. Как можно побороться с этим? Ну и почему не вызывается конвертер в таком случае?

P.S. Надо именно на C#, xaml не катит - прошлый пост)

Comment: Зачем городить такие сложности? Почему просто не создать свойство типа `bool` в классе вьюмодели и привязать его к чекбоксу, и в сеттере свойства вызвать нужную вам команду, а?

Comment: Мультибиндинг вам тут ничем не поможет, он вообще по другое. Поместите ваши значения в один класс и передавайте экземпляр этого класса

Comment: И да, привязка устанавливается не так как вы написали, а с помощью метода SetBinding